# How to persist oauth access tokens in spring security JDBC?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-data-rest, spring-security-oauth2

When the user login I generate a token so when the user want to access information of RESTapi he will not login again , the code works but I have a problem.

The token that spring generate works but when I recompile the code I wrote, this token doesn't work anymore and I should request a new token to use the "bearer $Token " is this a normal behavior or I should fix something in the settings?

Example :

`curl -u test: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d "grant_type=password&username=id&password=pass"`

`{"access_token":"a46c3cf4-6777-4a61-9f71-268be047c383","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"8ef69c18-1a9e-47c0-ba80-b51a34144e9a","expires_in":603005,"scope":"read write trust"}`

When I recompile the code :

`curl -u test: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d "grant_type=password&username=id&password=pass"`

`{"access_token":"1a69f140-47ac-4dde-9786-1d4f14f9a389","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"be99d434-54a0-4273-add8-cccad95caec3","expires_in":604799,"scope":"read write trust"}`

this is my code :

```
import com.lms.entities.UsersEntity;
import com.lms.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
class SpringBackendScoutApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBackendScoutApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers(
                            Constants.USERS, Constants.COMMENTS, Constants.FRIENDS_REQUEST,
                            Constants.MUSICS, Constants.PHOTOS, Constants.POSTS, Constants.VIDEOS,
                            Constants.PROFILE_PHOTOS, Constants.FRIENDS, "/"
                    ).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                    .and().logout();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("sparklr");
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("test")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("sparklr")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(7))

            ;
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            for (UsersEntity user : userRepository.findAll())
                if (user.getUsername() != null && user.getPassword() != null)
                    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user.getUsername()).password(user.getPassword()).roles("USER");
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
                throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve the problem , you should add a token store to persist the token generated each time :

```
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String oauthClass;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String oauthUrl;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        DataSource tokenDataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                        .driverClassName(oauthClass)
                        .username("root")
                        .password("")
                        .url(oauthUrl)
                        .build();
        return new JdbcTokenStore(tokenDataSource);
    }
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("scout").tokenStore(tokenStore());
}
```

For the other class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }  
}
```

In applications.properties it should be configured :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and Finally you should add the two tables in your database :

```
create table oauth_access_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token BLOB,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(256),
  client_id VARCHAR(256),
  authentication BLOB,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(256)
);

create table oauth_refresh_token (
  token_id VARCHAR(256),
  token BLOB,
  authentication BLOB
);
```

Comment: Does it store by default in those tables

Comment: yes if you write all the code I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: How does it know to use the table names defined in the schema? Can I name those without the oauth_ preceding for example?

Answer (score 1):

By default, an in memory token store is configured. If you want to persist the tokens between restarts then you need to configure a persistent token store (JdbcTokenStore for example)

Edit to add steps:

[This SQL will create the basic schema that you need.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)

Create a DataSource bean connected to the database containing that schema and then add the following bean to your OAuth config

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource; 

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: please do you have any example I can follow ?

Comment: Please could you specify all steps , I added the tables to my database and added the code you mentioned to my code but still how can the "Datasource" know my database. I modified my code too :  `@Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("sparklr").tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }`

Comment: Data sources are pretty simple to configure:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: I did this configuration `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scout
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` still I have the problem of token get changed everytime I recompile the code.The tables I added does not store any token , are you sure I should add only the lines of code you gave me ?

Comment: Could you further clarify this whole example? I am also struggling with the same issue and am not able to resolve it yet.

Comment: @ph1lb4 check my answer

Comment: Thanks but we ended up using our own MongoDB to store the tokens.